# Having trouble with t-d, t-d, d-t and d-d clusters

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, consonant-clusters

Consider the words:

1. Practice twice and practiced twice (t-t)
2. Dance down and danced down (t-d)
3. Play down and played down (d-d)
4. Increase double and increased double (d-d)

I can transcribe these into IPA into problem but I have a problem distinguishing between the normal form and the -ed form in each case. In casual speech, most native speakers of American English don't release that final -ed sound (like in songs and all) and it gets merged in some weird way and I have no clue if it's a glottal stop or an unrelease stop or if it changes a vowel quality in any way. How would a native speaker distinguish between these minimal pairs?

For some reason though I can kind of tell the difference between play down and played down. Probably because of the fact that "play" end in a vowel so the boundaries are clearly heard

Comment: This is usually about context. Your 1), 2) and 4) are unlikely collocations.  For 3), we would say: They played down the problem. And not: They play down the problem [every month]. Context usually clarifies intention so it really doesn't matter as the listener mentally sorts it out....

Comment: Only by context, I think, unless the speaker was being especially careful.

Comment: @Lambie I am aware of that. I was just using them for the sake of making an example and I couldn't come up with any better words that was actually used more regularly

Comment: I will tell you that in Spanish, for years, I kept hearing (and saying)  a thing like this: Así declaro, which means: "And so say I" as an emphatic phrase. (in legal language, it is I so declare or state). When it's actually: Así de claro, which means: This or it could not be clearer. And it's really funny *because* as a retort to someone, *either one usually works*. And I have not been able to come up with a similar homophone phrase in English.

Comment: For me, the only slight difference between ***play down*** and ***played down*** is a *very brief glottal stop* between the two words in the second case. And in rapid / relaxed speech, any such distinction could easily disappear completely.

Comment: A native speaker can do two things: Get it from the context OR ask the other person to repeat it. But as I said, the context will usually indicate which is which, so there is no need to take it further.

Answer (score 1):

In cases "3" the context of pronunciation is that of *double consonant sounds*, in particular that of double plosives; the key to the pronunciation is given in *Longman Pronunciation dictionary*, p. 238.

> 1. Double consonant sounds ('geminates') are found in English only across grammatical boundaries: where two words occur next to one another in connected speech, or in the two parts of a compound word, or a stem and an affix. They always straddle a syllable boundary, too.
> 2. Although cases like these consist of two identical phonemes in succession, they are not usually pronounced as two distinct complete sounds. The details depend on their manner of ARTICULATION.
>
> - **Fricatives, nasals, liquids** […]
> - **Plosives**: a geminate is pronounced like a single sound, with just one sequence of approach—hold—release (see PLOSIVE); but in a geminate the hold is longer. In **big game** ˌbɪg ˈgeɪm there is a single phonetic "g:" between two vowels, straddling the syllable boundary. Exceptionally, because of the possibility of a GLOTTAL STOP, a geminated t may consist phonetically of ʔt: **that time** ˌðæt 'taɪm; but a single long alveolar "t:" is also possible.
> - **Affricates** […]

- Practice twice        ˌprækt ɪs ˈtwaɪs             practiced twice         ˌprækt ɪst ˈtwaɪs
- (similarly for "play(ed) down" and "increase(d) double")

In case "1", "2" and "4" it is not clear to me what can happen.

Comment: Note that in geminated/doubled plosives, the first one is unreleased: [p̚p]

Comment: @Void It seems to me that, rather, there are not two plosives since from the first is only taken the hold stage, and instead that there is, as claimed in the dictionary, a new, longer  sound similar to t, but  in which the  the hold stage is long.

Comment: *Played down* is indeed a geminate consonant, which is probably how the OP can distinguish it from *play down*. But do you have a reference that says that English speakers use geminates for the sound combinations /st.t/ and /st.d/, as in 1, 2, 4?   I think they're pretty much indistinguishable, which explains why the OP can't tell them apart.

Comment: @PeterShor I have no reference for that and am not too familiar with any particular accent, but it seems that careful pronunciation of "first to finish", where a geminate t is preserved would be rare compared to a pronunciation where a single t is heard.

Comment: In most cases, a native speaker will ask for clarification is there is any doubt. So this doesn't *really* answer the question. If I say: I practiced twice today. I am not saying: I practice twice every day. So....

Comment: @Lambie It does answer a part of the question since the question asks about clues whether or not glottal stop could be used. The dictionary says yes, glottal stop can be used by some speakers.

Comment: @Lambie You are justifying the undifferentiated pronunciation, which is one thing. A language clue may be found sufficient. However that is not the question; it is rather "What do we hear usually? What should we hear?".

Comment: Peter Shor has answered that part of the question. I am adding to it: I said when in doubt, one asks for clarification or repetition, at which point, the sound is made clearer, one hopes. Sorry, there is no such thing as "we should hear". We hear what we hear.....

Comment: @Lambie No, I don't agree; we hear what we hear when we listen to a foreigner with a strong accent, for instance, but we know that we should hear something else if the speaker was a native speaker.

Comment: But it's the opposite case here: A non-native listening to a native.  The OP is non-native. But in any case, one hears what one hears.

Comment: @LPH: the OP thinks he should hear a difference between *practice twice* and *practiced twice*, or *clasp pin* and *class pin* (say). He doesn't, and is asking what he should be listening for. The native speakers here are saying that because of the /s/, there ***is*** no difference for examples 1, 2, and 4 (unlike for his third example, *played down* and *play down*, where the difference is gemination).

Comment: Being a native English (US) speaker, there IS a difference in all the examples - but a geminate is easily lost in the hearing. Thus context becomes the difference, or asking for clarification. And, unlike LPH, I think example 2 also fits the plosive/geminate usage case. IMO, the Longman pronunciation dictionary quote is a precise answer to the OP. The differences may be hard to hear, but Longmans, addresses the positioning of the tongue and the breath patterns that make the difference happen ( one sequence of approach—hold—release . . . in a geminate the hold is longer . . .).

Comment: @PeterShor There is an error in "1/" and "4/": the consonants must be the phonetic consonants. It seems to me that often the speakers do not use the long plosive and instead, what one can hear is quite similar to the pronunciation of a single plosive. It must be said that the long plosive requires much practice, it is difficult to place.